# How to prevent JavaFX webview from connecting to internet?

Tags: javafx

I have some local HTML's which I want to open with webview and then find place of images and do some work on them. because they are local, I want to prevent webview and webengine from connecting to internet, because this cause them work slower.
How can I do this work?

Comment: How do you know they work slower if you don't know how to prevent them to connect?

Comment: Because when I disconnect my laptop from internet it works faster.